# ifconfig in layout xml for enable disable when change file .phtml

Tags: layout, footer, ifconfig

Good evening, I have some problems with my module. I am using the `ifconfig` option in my .xml module in the theme folder layout, and my option in the admin (ENABLE / DISABLE) works, but to disable are not carrying the original file footer.phtml (folder `rwd/default/template/page/html/`). Resulting in a blank footer .... I need to load the default file footer instead of my custom `footer.phtml` when my module is disabled by the admin config, how to proceed?

The code I'm using is:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <!-- set a new file customized for module footer.phtml -->
            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="customizefooter/options/custom_enable_cf">
                    <template>customizefooter/footer.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Also see: http://pastebin.com/DT2UMt2C

Comment: Try make second action with ifconfig disabled or without ifconfig.

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the footer template and haveing a second action which has a `ifconfig`, so the template is only reset `ifconfig`?